# synchronous retrofit with sqlite

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite, retrofit2

I have 3000 more records from `sqlserver` that I want to put in `sqlite` on my `Android` project
and the result is an error. can anyone give me an example of a correct script or library that can be used to sync `sqlite` with `sqlserver` thx.

`JSON` from server

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "count": 4531,
    "pesan": "Data Ditemukan",
    "CekBrgBru": [
        {
            "Kode": "1\/000001",
            "PartNumber": "AABIBA0101AY-1",
            "NamaBrg": "STANG KROSI 1\/2\" LIPPRO",
            "Keterangan": "BONUS",
            "Jenis": "1\/000013",
            "Merek": "1\/000083",
            "Tipe": "1\/00051",
            "Klasifikasi": null,
            "UpdateBy": "Z0\/SA",
            "UpdateDate": "2016-08-20 11:34:27",
            "CreateBy": "Z0\/SA",
            "CreateDate": "2013-12-08 11:22:45",
            "ImagePath1": null,
            "ImagePath2": null,
            "ImagePath3": null,
            "ImagePath4": null,
            "ImagePath5": null
        },
        {
            "Kode": "1\/000002",
            "PartNumber": "AABIBA0101AY-1",
            "NamaBrg": "KUNCI RING PAS SET 8-24MM(11PC) MULTIPRO",
            "Keterangan": null,
            "Jenis": "1\/000013",
            "Merek": "1\/000099",
            "Tipe": "1\/00489",
            "Klasifikasi": null,
            "UpdateBy": "Z0\/SA",
            "UpdateDate": "2016-08-20 12:13:34",
            "CreateBy": "Z0\/SA",
            "CreateDate": "2013-12-08 11:22:45",
            "ImagePath1": null,
            "ImagePath2": null,
            "ImagePath3": null,
            "ImagePath4": null,
            "ImagePath5": null
        }
      ]
}
```

this is my script

```
public void onResponse(Call<RetrofitBarang> call, Response<RetrofitBarang> response) {
                        int status = response.body().getStatus();
                        int count = response.body().getCount();
                        String pesan = response.body().getPesan();
                        for (int i = 0; 1 < count; i++){
                            myDB.inserBarang(response.body().getDatabarang().get(i).getKode(),
                                    response.body().getDatabarang().get(i).getPartNumber(),
                                    response.body().getDatabarang().get(i).getNamaBrg(),
                                    response.body().getDatabarang().get(i).getKeterangan(),
                                    response.body().getDatabarang().get(i).getJenis(),
                                    response.body().getDatabarang().get(i).getMerek(),
                                    response.body().getDatabarang().get(i).getTipe(),
                                    response.body().getDatabarang().get(i).getKlasifikasi(),
                                    response.body().getDatabarang().get(i).getUpdateBy(),
                                    response.body().getDatabarang().get(i).getUpdateDate(),
                                    response.body().getDatabarang().get(i).getCreateBy(),
                                    response.body().getDatabarang().get(i).getCreateDate()
                            );
                            myDB.closeDatabase();
                        }
                    }
```

and i got this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cornel.cornelselesorder, PID: 18534
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.cornel.cornelselesorder.SplashActivity$1.onResponse(SplashActivity.java:99)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; 1 < count; i++){` I think you mean `i < count`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Ah, my bad, thx bro